# Stored procedure with multiple result sets very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I use EF6 with ObjectContext + edmx model. There is a stored procedure with multiple result sets. It turned out every time we call .GetNextResult it dynamically compiles new method making huge overhead and performance hit. I used Perfview and JIT compilation statistics to figure that out.

```
using (var db = new SomeEntities()) 
{ 
    var resultSet1 = db.GetAllData(); 
    // handle result set 1 data

    // This causes new dynamically emitted method to be JIT-compiled.
    var resultSet2 = resultSet1.GetNextResult<Class2>(); 
}
```

Are there ways to eliminate dynamic compilation and still use .GetNextResult?
So far I have to revert back to old ADO.net data reader like showed in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that works much faster, than .GetNextResult and at the same time less "manual" comparing to ADO.Net DataReader.
It is .Translate method. There is [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) describing how to use it. Basically

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]";
db.Database.Connection.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Read first result set
var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<EFStoredProcJit.Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

// Read 2nd result set
reader.NextResult();
var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<EFStoredProcJit.Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

I wrote [blog post](http://blog.dlevchenko.com/2015/10/30/EF-and-multiple-result-sets-stored-procedure/) with more details on this and sample app.